# Ubuntu One Preferences does not show usage, name, e-mail, current plan

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

Ubuntuone is correctly synchronizing selected files between two computers running Ubuntu 10.10.  When I open Ubuntuone Preferences, Account tab, on one computer it does not display the usage, name e-mail or current plan.  On the other computer all information is shown correctly.  On the Devices tab the 2 computers are not shown.  They do show correctly on the other computer.  Any ideas on how to fix this problem.  I have reinstalled Ubuntuone per this **[link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/HowDoICompletelyRemoveAndReinstallUbuntuOne)**.

I have installed gir1.0-soup2.4 and magicicada. I have downloaded watgui.py but I don't know how to run it, do I need to put it in a certain directory?? With magicicada I can see traffic when I change a file. Let me know what you would like to look at.

I have run python watgui.py with the following results:

```
  "username": "https://login.ubuntu.com/+id/C3b7HxG", 
"openid": "https://login.ubuntu.com/+id/C3b7HxG", 
"first_name": "", 
"last_name": "James Schurz", 
"features": [
    "couch_storage", 
    "file_storage", 
    "notes_sync"
], 
"couchdb": {
    "host": "https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com", 
    "root": "https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/u/a76/8a9/662864", 
    "dbpath": "u/a76/8a9/662864"
}, 
"couchdb_root": "https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/u/a76/8a9/662864", 
"email": "pjschurz@yahoo.com", 
"current_plan": "Ubuntu One Basic (2 GB)\nTotal storage: 2 GB", 
"nickname": "James Schurz", 
"id": 662864, 
"subscription": {
    "upgrade_available": true, 
    "description": "Ubuntu One Basic (2 GB)", 
    "upgrade_option": {
        "upgrade_url": "https://one.ubuntu.com/account/subscription/591444/upgrade/662864/", 
        "price": 2.9900000000000002, 
        "description": "20-Pack with 20 GB (monthly)", 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "id": 591444, 
        "name": "20-Pack with 20 GB (monthly)"
    }, 
    "trial": false, 
    "started": "2010-09-06T19:27:10Z", 
    "is_paid": false, 
    "expires": null, 
    "qty": 1, 
    "price": 0.0, 
    "currency": "USD", 
    "id": 591444, 
    "name": "Ubuntu One Basic (2 GB)"
}
```

Reported out as a [bug #708902](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/708902).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Ubuntu One is dead.

Answer (score 2):

That's very strange. The information (both the account info such as email and name, and the devices) is pulled over the network doing an oauth-signed REST request, using the same token the `syncdaemon` uses to connect.

Could you install [gir1.0-soup-2.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gir1.0-soup-2.4) [image: Install gir1.0-soup-2.4]
(or [gir1.2-soup-2.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gir1.2-soup-2.4) [image: Install gir1.2-soup-2.4] if you're in Natty), [python-beautifulsoup](http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-beautifulsoup) [image: Install python-beautifulsoup], [python-gtksourceview2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-gtksourceview2) [image: Install python-gtksourceview2], download [watgui.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chipaca/+junk/watgui/download/john.lenton%40canonical.com-20100927195353-mwn8tuxf433d2y7r/watgui.py-20100926175725-w002ripb3p6x8f7h-1/watgui.py), run `python ~/Downloads/watgui.py` in a Terminal (assuming `~/Downloads` is the folder to which you downloaded it), and see if you can see your account information and devices using that tool?

If you can successfully get your account information using `watgui.py` on the same computer and account where `ubuntuone-preferences` fails to do so, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug?field.title=%5Bmaverick%5D+ubuntuone-preferences+not+showing+account+information) or, if you'd rather, hop on to the [#ubuntuone channel on freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=%23ubuntuone) and look me up.

---

In any case, if you're sure your `syncdaemon` is connected on the computer that is not showing this information (and especially if `watgui` was able to get the account information), you should be OK; I'd appreciate it if you could install [magicicada](http://packages.ubuntu.com/magicicada) [image: Install magicicada] just to be sure. It would be very interesting to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I have installed gir1.0-soup2.4 and magicicada.  I have downloaded watgui.py but I don't know how to run it, do I need to put it in a certain directory??  With magicicada I can see traffic when I change a file.  Let me know what you would like to look at.

Comment: Assuming you downloaded `watgui.py` to your `~/Downloads` directory, open Terminal and enter: `cd ~/Downloads; python watgui.py` (followed by enter), and then when the watgui window comes up hit enter again. You should see your account information in the main window.

Comment: @Jim I've stuck a bounty on this, can you update your question with the results from Chipaca's suggestions?

Comment: @Chipaca I get the following error when running python watgui.py in the downloads directory where watgui.py is located:  ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Comment: @Jim Ah! Forgot that. Install [python-beautifulsoup](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-beautifulsoup), and also [python-gtksourceview2](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/python-gtksourceview2), and try again. Will edit my answer once we've gotten all the dependencies right :)

Comment: @Jim meanwhile, have you looked at magicicada? What does it have to say?

Comment: @Chipaca I have installed beautifulsoup and python watgui.py now works.  See edited question for results.

Comment: The watgui.py output is fine. Please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug?field.title=%5Bmaverick%5D+ubuntuone-preferences+not+showing+account+information) and/or [hop on freenode](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=%23ubuntuone) so we can look at this interactively.

Comment: @Chipaca I have looked at magicicada.  When a file is changed I have seen traffic in the upper and lower panes.  I don't know what I should be looking for with this program.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had similar, although not identical, behavior on my system.  Following the steps in the first comment on this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/658437) resolved the issue for me.

> 1. Quit the Ubuntu One client (open a terminal window & run "u1sdtool -q;
>      killall ubuntuone-login" without the
>      quotes)
> 2. Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords
>      and Encryption Keys
> 3. Click on the plus symbol next to "Passwords: login" to expand the list
> 4. Right-click on the Ubuntu One token and select "Delete"
> 5. Go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/
> 6. Click on the checkbox next to your computer
> 7. Click the "Remove selected computers" button
> 8. Open System --> Preferences -->Ubuntu One
> 9. a web page should open, prompting you to add your computer to your
>      Ubuntu One account
> 10. Add your computer